# How can I get comments when I have facebook post id

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I want to fetch all comments of a post on facebook (my post and my friends post) using my access token.
I already have a post id, but when I call `FB.api('/{post_id}/comments?access_token=xxxx)`, it returns error code 100 with the description:

> Unsupported get request. Object with ID
>   '988927087866664_1344444165648286' does not exist, cannot be loaded
>   due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please
>   read the Graph API documentation at
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

[image: Error Image]

Facebook also approved publish_actions permission for my website.
Thank you for your help

Comment: You need `user_posts` permission from the user who made the post.

Comment: Thanh you for your answer. I am trying to get "user_posts" permission.